# populating a dropdown box, based on the selection of another dropdown box using php, mqsql and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate a drop down box, based on a selection from another drop down box.  Here is what I have for php code:

```
<form id="inventory" method="POST" action="">
   <fieldset>
      <label for="area" >Select Shelf Area</label>
      <select id="area" name="area">
          <option value=""></option>

          <?php $area = $conn->query("
             select substring_index(location, ' ', 1) as area
             FROM location GROUP BY substring_index(location, ' ', 1)");

             while ($row = $area->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['area'] . '" >' . $row['area'] . '</option>';
             }
          >
      </select><br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I run my query, all is fine, but I need to take the results of this and use it to populate another drop down box ( the <'value from previous drop down '>) which is here:

```
echo "<label for='location' id='label'>Select location:</label>";
echo "<select id='location' name='location'>";
echo "<option value=''>--Select Location--</option>";
$query = "SELECT location_id, location FROM location
    WHERE location LIKE '<value from previous drop down box>'
    ORDER BY location";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['location'] . '" >' . $row['location'] . '</option>';
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue using *JavaScript* and *Ajax*:

```
$("#area").change (function(){
    $("#acctRecords tbody tr").remove();
    $('#label').show();
    $('#label2').show();
    $('#location').show();
    $('#section').show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: "area.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: ({area: $('#area').val()}),
        success: function(data) {
            $('select#location').empty();
            $('select#location').append('<option value="0">Select Option</option>');

            //Populate options of the second dropdown
            for(var x = 0; x < data.id.length; x++) {
                $('select#location').append('<option value="'+data.id[x]+'">'+data.location[x]+'</option>');
            } //end of each function

        } // end of success
    }); // end of ajax call
}); // end of area change function
```

This posts to my HTML of:

```
echo"<label for='location' id='label'>Select location:</label>";
echo"<select id='location' name='location'>";
echo"</select><br />";
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function in the wrong way.

In your 1st `SELECT` you might not be getting any output or may be blank rows.

According to the [website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) -

> **SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)**
>
> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

Comment: I am getting results from the first select perfectly, but I need to use the results from the query to populate the 2nd drop down box.