# Change the value of a select after a query in database triggered by the change of another select

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i got a form with two selects,
Select 1 and Select 2, both of them are filled with options from a mysql database, wich have a relation.
ej: select 1 = car model
    select 2 = car brand
when i select a model, ej: focus i need to change the current brand to ford.
the relation that exist between ford and focus is given in the database, 
HOW can i ask the database and change the select value with the response of the database?, ive tried 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp that tutorial BUT i dont know how to modify it to return a value insted of printing the result.

The real case:

database:
Table Name : Region ( id_region, nombre_region )
Table Name : Provincia ( nombre_provincia, id_provincia, id_region )

The form:

...

```
  <label>Region: </label>
  <select name="region" id="region">
  <?php include('lista_region.php'); ?> //this makes the list asking the database, works fine.
  </select>

  <label>Provincia: </label>
  <select name="provincia" id="provincia" onchange="HERE_I_NEED_HELP()">
  <?php include('lista_provincia.php'); ?> //this makes the list asking the database, works fine.
  </select>
```

in the "HERE_I_NEED_HELP()" i need to select the id_region from the database where the value of "provincia" matches the one in the DB, and then change the value of "region" to the one that i just got from the DB,

Comment: btw, i also tried with webservice but i dont know how to ask a webservice from javascript, some guidance in that area would be nice too, btw im new in php, its quite easy to understand but still a newbie :P

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885125/populating-a-dropdown-box-based-on-the-selection-of-another-dropdown-box-using

Comment: Can you show us some minimal effort? Like how the DB looks, what code you have so far, etc..

Comment: i think that with the example that i give its quite clar, but ok, ill edit now.

Comment: @jim its a good guide, but i need to change the value, i already populate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what i did to resolve the problem was calla function that invoques a webservice (this deals with the server and returns a json with the answer), and with that return i change it to the new value, the function that does the magic :

```
  <script>
  function buscarregion(){
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = function () {
        var resultado = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("region".value = reulstado.data;
  };
  var service = "webservice.php?param="
  var x = document.getElementById("provincia").value
  x = web.concat(x);
  oReq.open("get", x, true);
  oReq.send();
  }
```

Thats all!!, the webservice does the search with the param send in x and returns the value that i want and i print it in "region", hope this helps someone with my same question. thx for the comments.

ps: buscarregion() replaces the HERE_I_NEED_HELP()